# Can't connect Cura to my Anet A8 on OSX 10.11.6

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anet-a8

I finished the mount of my Anet A8, tested everything and apparently it was ok. I installed the driver that came with it, `CH341SER_MAC`, turned on the printer, connect USB cable, but nothing happened.

In Cura, I tried to add a printer many times and this message always appears

> The printer isn't connected.

In OSX, I discover in System Information, an **USB2.0-Serial**, that I think can be the printer.  Is it a printer driver problem? Is it the Cura setting? I'm completely lost...

[image: OSX System Information - USB]

Comment: check @Sevasuslik 's reply, the drivers were not the issue, Cura is.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of problems with the CH340 chipset drivers to be found on 3D SE and various forums on the internet. To use this cheap CH340 chip that is used by a number of Arduino compatible (clone) boards to provide USB connectivity (a USB bus converter chip that converts USB bus signals to serial interface) you need to install a correct working driver.

For Mac OS X you can try to download a working version for the OS system you are using. You can try to use [this driver installer](https://blog.sengotta.net/signed-mac-os-driver-for-winchiphead-ch340-serial-bridge/) or [this driver installer](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver). Both reported to work with Mac OS.

---

**Edit**: If you are using OSX El Capitan, please read [this](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/blog?journal_blog_post_id=7&lang=en). To  get the CH340 drivers to work you need to use the tool **csrutil**.

> - Reboot and press CMD+R immediately after hearing the startup sound to boot to Recovery Mode
> - Open Terminal
> - Execute the following command: `csrutil enable --without kext`
> - Reboot

More information is found [here](https://tzapu.com/making-ch340-ch341-serial-adapters-work-under-el-capitan-os-x/)!

Comment: 0scar, do you think that I should delete my answer? It isn't El Capitan specific (because I hadn't read the question correctly), doesn't provide a definitive answer that works, and is quite long winded. I have turned it into [an on-going blog](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2018/07/02/ch340-on-os-x/)  instead. The OP hasn't returned to say what the solution to his issue was.

Answer (score 2):

*You are using OSX El Capitan. The version of OSX is **particularly** relevant w.r.t. the CH340 drivers. A driver that works on one OSX version, **will not necessarily work** with a different version of OSX - even minor version changes of OSX can be affected (as the answers to [Problem with serial driver for CH340G board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19059/problem-with-serial-driver-for-ch340g-board) demonstrate.*

---

#### Important Note

Before installing *any* new drivers, it is always worth backing up the original file, just to avoid any unpleasantness later. For example:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext.old
```

---

I seem to remember having the same issue, not with a 3D printer, but just with a cloned Arduino board. I thought that I had written a lengthy blog about it but can't locate it at the moment (I will update this answer when I find it)<sup>1</sup>.

The CH34x ICs are infamous for their poor support on OSX. On Windows they generally fare a little better, and TBH it is probably well worth considering a WinTel option just to save yourself time, frustration and headaches...

Nevertheless, I think that I found this site to be useful, [How To Use Cheap Chinese Arduinos That Come With With CH340G / CH341G Serial/USB Chip (Windows & Mac OS-X)](https://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html).

See also [Compatibility between Arduino and Arduino clones](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71/compatibility-between-arduino-and-arduino-clones/13414#13414):

> The most annoying issue, and even then it is quite minor, is that a lot of Chinese clones do not use an ATMega for the USB and instead use a CH340G. These chips, while fine when connecting to a PC running Windows 7, have great difficulties with the drivers on OS X, and end up just not being recognised. It is possible [to find a driver for the CH340G](https://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html), but when I installed it, it immediately crashed the MacBook, upon plugging in the cloned UNO..!

This advice also proved to be invaluable, from [Post #47 - Arduino in OS X 10.9 Mavericks - Serial Port Issues](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=198539.msg2151505#msg2151505)

> For any others who haven't been able to solve this one yet: if, like
>   me, you decided to go with the cheaper chinese kick off arduino clone
>   boards and had problems similar to this one, please check the
>   following forum post, as it solved the problem for me:
>
> http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=289518.0
>
> And another blog site that explains the whole process really simply
>   for noobs like me:
>
> http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html
>
> Actually the dude has even mirrored the relevant driver that solves
>   the problem without having to find it on an all chinese or all russian
>   website!

---

Finally, I have just had a problem with an Arduino Nano and my Mac (running Mountain Lion). Using this link, [Connect Arduino Nano with Mac OSX](https://medium.com/@thuc/connect-arduino-nano-with-mac-osx-f922a46c0a5d):

> 1. Download the driver from [url](https://github.com/ledongthuc/example/blob/master/file/CH34x_Install_V1.3.zip): link
> 2. Extract and install file `CH34x_Install.pkg`
> 3. Run the command: `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"`
> 4. Restart the Mac.
> 5. Replace the text `-P{serial.port}` to `"-P{serial.port}"` in 2 files:
>      `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt` (1 instance)
>      `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/programmers.txt` (4 instances)

However, this did not work for me, but I am running OS X 10.8.5 and the driver is meant for 10.9 (according to the `ReadMe.pdf`). My `/System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext` file remained unchanged (i.e. the date did not change), so maybe the installer will not work for 10.8.5.

I tried the second of 0scar's suggestions, but this didn't work for me either (on **Mountain Lion**): [adrianmihalko/CH340G CH34G CH34X Mac OS X driver](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver) - The `usb.kext` file was never installed in `/System/Library/Extensions/` by either the 1.3 or 1.4 versions.

The first of 0scar's links, [Signed Mac OS Driver for Winchiphead CH340 serial bridge](https://blog.sengotta.net/signed-mac-os-driver-for-winchiphead-ch340-serial-bridge/), interestingly pointed out that, *after* installation (and the associated reboot), one may have to copy the `usbserial.ktext` file manaually to /System/Library/Extensions/`. So after locating the installed file I did the following:

```
sudo mv /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext
```

and then rebooted once again.

Note the change of the filename - this may or may not be necessary. Either way, when I used both `usbserial.kext` and `usb.kext`, *yet again*, this did not help me on Mountain Lion. However, the documents do state that this particular driver is for 10.9 (Mavericks) through to 10.13 (High Sierra).

[The answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53139/uploading-to-a-ch340-nano-board-using-a-mac-with-osx-high-sierra#answer-53611) to this question, [Uploading to a CH340 “Nano” board using a Mac with Osx High Sierra](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53139/uploading-to-a-ch340-nano-board-using-a-mac-with-osx-high-sierra), may help you on **OSX High Sierra**.

It might be worth trawling through this list of questions on the Arduino.SE site: [`osx nano`](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=osx%20nano), such as this one [Rename device name (ch340 usb to serial) Mac OS](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/rename-device-name-ch340-usb-to-serial-mac-os/13344).

---

#### Additional note

Another pitfall is that some drivers may be named `CH341xx.xxx`, but they may work for both the CH340 *and* the CH340... then again, they may not. The docs don't always say whether they will or not work for both ICs.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I think it might be this [Re: Arduino in OS X 10.9 Mavericks - Serial Port Issues](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=198539.msg2151553#msg2151553):

> Yes, I have been struggling for a month or so, and finally realised
>   (after reading
>   http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=198539.15#msg1720630) that
>   other chips were being used, in lieu of the FTDI chip, for example the
>   Prolific 2305. After inspecting the board with a magnifying glass, I
>   saw that I did not have an FTDI chip in my Chinese clones of an Uno
>   and a Mega, but a CH340G instead.
>
> Once I realised that I found the http://wch.cn/product/CH340.html
>   site, but the Mac driver doesn't appear to be there. After a bit more
>   googling I found [the kiguino site](http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html). I downloaded the mirrored driver,
>   rebooted the mac, and when I connected the Uno, my MacBook died and
>   restarted with the grey serious error screen and refused to boot.
>   After disconnecting the Uno, the Mac rebooted as normal, so no lasting
>   damage done, but I am a bit wary of trying to plug the clone in again.
>
> Anyway, note that the chip says CH340 on it, but the drivers are
>   CH341. I assume that they are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in drivers! In the file located at Ultimate Cura -> Contents/Resources/USBPrinting/AutoDetectBaudJob.py in line 74 in the if statement you should replace `and` with `or`:

```
if b"ok" in line or b"T:" in line: # or instead of and
```

Answer (score -3):

What Cura version do you have?
Cura only works with the Anet A8 via USB on versions 2.3 and lower according to this [page](https://www.thingiverse.com/groups/anet-a8-prusa-i3/forums/general/topic:12212). The page is from thingiverse(A 3d printing forum + print files page)

Comment: Link answers are not answers.