# Creality 4.2.7 problem connecting to Windows

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-5

I've had an Ender 5 for quite a while and it has worked phenomenally, but recently I had encountered a MIN_TEMP error so I ordered a new hotend and Creality silent board.

Because this is an Ender 5, I had to change the firmware from the default on the new board and I did that using VS Code. I changed all the parameters I need to but when I plugged in the printer to upload the code, the printer shows up under USB in device manager but with the error:

> There are no compatible drivers for this device.

As a beginner, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SE.3DP! Out of curiosity, was the MIN_TEMP error persistent? Had you checked the cables/etc before ordering a replacement?

Comment: Just out of interest, which version of Windows? 7, 10, or something else (Win95)?

Comment: The MIN_TEMP error was persistent. I replaced the hot end and double checked the wiring but my hotend temperature read as -14C.

Comment: yep, that sounds about right. -15c is the default for a disconnected thermo

Comment: @Greenonline Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

By default, Windows does not come packaged with drivers for the CH340 USB Serial chipset the Creality Silent board has installed. To get your computer to properly recognize the printer, you will need to install the CH340 Driver software from WCH's [website.](https://wch-ic.com) (the company that manufactures the CH340 chip)

As of August 2021, the download for the drivers can be found at:
http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH341SER_EXE.html

Comment: Ironically, I have found that Windows 7 works well with the dreaded CH340, whereas it is *usually* OS X and Macs that [refuse to play ball correctly with the CH340](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6221/4762), and require additional drivers.